# Atari Breakout with levels and power up errors

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make this code for a project I have coming up. The goal is to have powerups when the ball hits some of the bricks and the power up does something like add a life or make the paddle bigger. Every time I try to run it I get some errors like `activatePowerUp` is not defined and some other errors and I was trying to figure out how to resolve this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    canvas {
          background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/sJTAxQG.jpeg");
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>group project</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
   <audio id="myAudio">
    <source src="8d82b5_Star_Wars_Main_Theme_Song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      </audio>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="950" height="500"></canvas>
  <script>
   
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
    var ballRadius = 10;
    var x = canvas.width / 2;
    var y = canvas.height - 20;
    var dx = 4;
    var dy = -4;
    var paddleHeight = 10;
    var paddleWidth = 75;
    var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
    var powerUpWidth = 20;
    var powerUpHeight = 20;
    var rightPressed = false;
    var leftPressed = false;
    var brickRowCount = 9;
    var brickColumnCount = 9;
    var brickWidth = 75;
    var brickHeight = 20;
    var brickPadding = 10;
    var brickOffsetTop = 30;
    var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
    var score = 0;
    var lives = 2;
    var level = 1;
    var powerUpX = 0;
    var powerUpY = 0;
    var powerUpDX = 0;
    var powerUpDY = 2;
    var powerUpType = " ";
    var powerUpDuration = 10;
    var powerUpStartTime = 0;
    var powerUpActive = false;
    var powerUpColors = {
      "extend": "green",
      "shrink": "red",
      "multiply": "blue",
      "extra-life": "yellow",
    };

    var powerUpFunctions = {
      "extend": function() { paddleWidth += 20; },
      "shrink": function() { paddleWidth -= 20; },
      "multiply": function() { dx *= 2; dy *= 2; },
      "extra-life": function() {lives += 1; },
    };
    
    var StarWars = document.getElementById("myAudio");

    var bricks = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
      bricks[c] = [];
      for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
        bricks[c][r] = {x: 0, y: 0, status: 1};
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
      if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = true;
      }
      else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = true;
      }
    }

    function keyUpHandler(e) {
      if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
      }
      else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
      }
    }

    StarWars.play();
    
    function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
      var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
        paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth / 2;
      }
    }
    function collisionDetection() {
      for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
          var b = bricks[c][r];
          if (b.status == 1) {
            if (x > b.x && x < b.x + brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y + brickHeight) {
              dy = -dy;
              b.status = 0;
              score++;
              
              
              if (score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
                alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATS!");
                document.location.reload();
              }
              else{
                level++
                brickRowCount++;
                brickColumnCount++;
                activatePowerUp("extra-life");
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function drawBall() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }
    function drawPaddle() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    }
    function drawBricks() {
      for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
          if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
            var brickX = (r * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
            var brickY = (c * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
            bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
            bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function drawPowerUp(){
      if(powerUpActive){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(powerUpX, powerUpY, powerUpWidth, powerUpHeight);
        ctx.fillstyle = powerUpColors[powerUpType];
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
    function drawScore() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
      ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, 8, 20);
    }
    function drawLives() {
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
      ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives, canvas.width - 65, 20);
    }

    function drawLevel(){
      ctx.font = "16px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
      ctx.fillText("Level : " +level, canvas.width/2-30, 20)
    }

    function draw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawBricks();
      drawBall();
      drawPaddle();
      drawPowerUp();
      drawLevel();
      drawScore();
      drawLives();
      collisionDetection();

      if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
      }
      if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
        dy = -dy;
      }
      else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
        if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
          dy = -dy;
          if(x < paddleX+paddleWidth/2 && dx > 0) {
            dx = -dx;
          } else if(x > paddleX + paddleWidth / 2 && dx < 0){
            dx = -dx;
          }
        }
        else {
          lives--;
          if (!lives) {
            alert("GAME OVER");
            document.location.reload();
          }
          else {
            x = canvas.width / 2;
            y = canvas.height - 30;
            dx = 3;
            dy = -3;
            paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
          }
        }
      }

      if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
        paddleX += 7;
      }
      else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
        paddleX -= 7;
      }

      if(powerUpActive){
        powerUpY += powerUpSpeed;
        if(powerUpY > canvas.height){
          deactivatePowerUp();
        } else if(powerUpY + powerUpHeight > canvas.height - paddleHeight && powerUpX && powerUpX < paddleX + paddleWidth){
          activatePowerUp(powerUpType);
          deactivatePowerUp(draw);
        }
      }

      x += dx;
      y += dy;
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    draw();
</script>
  <p><a href="index.html">Back Home</a></p>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to get rid of some things like `activatePowerUp` and it still didn't fix it.

### Snippet

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 20;
var dx = 4;
var dy = -4;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
var powerUpWidth = 20;
var powerUpHeight = 20;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 9;
var brickColumnCount = 9;
var brickWidth = 75;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
var score = 0;
var lives = 2;
var level = 1;
var powerUpX = 0;
var powerUpY = 0;
var powerUpDX = 0;
var powerUpDY = 2;
var powerUpType = " ";
var powerUpDuration = 10;
var powerUpStartTime = 0;
var powerUpActive = false;
var powerUpColors = {
  "extend": "green",
  "shrink": "red",
  "multiply": "blue",
  "extra-life": "yellow",
};

var powerUpFunctions = {
  "extend": function() {
    paddleWidth += 20;
  },
  "shrink": function() {
    paddleWidth -= 20;
  },
  "multiply": function() {
    dx *= 2;
    dy *= 2;
  },
  "extra-life": function() {
    lives += 1;
  },
};

var StarWars = document.getElementById("myAudio");

var bricks = [];
for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      status: 1
    };
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}

// StarWars.play();

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth / 2;
  }
}

function collisionDetection() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if (b.status == 1) {
        if (x > b.x && x < b.x + brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y + brickHeight) {
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;

          if (score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
            alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATS!");
            document.location.reload();
          } else {
            level++
            brickRowCount++;
            brickColumnCount++;
            activatePowerUp("extra-life");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBricks() {
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
      if (bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (r * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (c * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawPowerUp() {
  if (powerUpActive) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(powerUpX, powerUpY, powerUpWidth, powerUpHeight);
    ctx.fillstyle = powerUpColors[powerUpType];
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, 8, 20);
}

function drawLives() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives, canvas.width - 65, 20);
}

function drawLevel() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Level : " + level, canvas.width / 2 - 30, 20)
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBricks();
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawPowerUp();
  drawLevel();
  drawScore();
  drawLives();
  collisionDetection();

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }
  if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  } else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      dy = -dy;
      if (x < paddleX + paddleWidth / 2 && dx > 0) {
        dx = -dx;
      } else if (x > paddleX + paddleWidth / 2 && dx < 0) {
        dx = -dx;
      }
    } else {
      lives--;
      if (!lives) {
        alert("GAME OVER");
        document.location.reload();
      } else {
        x = canvas.width / 2;
        y = canvas.height - 30;
        dx = 3;
        dy = -3;
        paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
      }
    }
  }

  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }

  if (powerUpActive) {
    powerUpY += powerUpSpeed;
    if (powerUpY > canvas.height) {
      deactivatePowerUp();
    } else if (powerUpY + powerUpHeight > canvas.height - paddleHeight && powerUpX && powerUpX < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      activatePowerUp(powerUpType);
      deactivatePowerUp(draw);
    }
  }

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/sJTAxQG.jpeg");
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="950" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: _"I tried to get rid of some things like `activatePowerUp` and it still didn't fix it."_ If you are receiving errors stating, _"Uncaught ReferenceError: activatePowerUp is not defined"_; wouldn't you want to define it? The JS interpreter is complaining that no function by that name exists. You need to implement it. Where did you define the `activatePowerUp` function?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I would do that, but my teacher gave me that code and I dont know how to define it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define stuff like:

```js
var powerUpSpeed = 2;        // not sure what this should be...
var paddleColor = "#0095DD"; // Default paddle color, will change with power-up

function activatePowerUp(powerUpType) {
  powerUpActive = true;
  paddleColor = powerUpColors[powerUpType];
  powerUpFunctions[powerUpType]();
}

function deactivatePowerUp() {
  powerUpActive = false;
  paddleColor = "#0095DD";
}
```

Also, you should loop over rows, then columns. I flipped the `r` and `c` loop variables in the code below. Also, when you lose the powerup, there is no way to revert the speed or size changes that were applied. These should be temporal adjustments made when updating the speed. You should not be overriding the base speed and size of the paddle.

One thing I noticed is that the number of bricks (rows and cols) increases int he collision detection check. I commented this out. Not sure why are you are checking for a win condition every time.

You should learn how to debug your code.

### "Working" example

I removed most (if all) errors, but you still need to fix some of the logic.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height - 20;
var dx = 4;
var dy = -4;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
var powerUpWidth = 20;
var powerUpHeight = 20;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 9;
var brickColumnCount = 9;
var brickWidth = 75;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
var score = 0;
var lives = 2;
var level = 1;
var powerUpX = 0;
var powerUpY = 0;
var powerUpDX = 0;
var powerUpDY = 2;
var powerUpType = " ";
var powerUpDuration = 10;
var powerUpStartTime = 0;
var powerUpActive = false;
var powerUpColors = {
  "extend": "green",
  "shrink": "red",
  "multiply": "blue",
  "extra-life": "yellow",
};

var powerUpFunctions = {
  "extend": function() {
    paddleWidth += 20;
  },
  "shrink": function() {
    paddleWidth -= 20;
  },
  "multiply": function() {
    dx *= 2;
    dy *= 2;
  },
  "extra-life": function() {
    lives += 1;
  },
};

var powerUpSpeed = 2;
var paddleColor = "#0095DD";
function activatePowerUp(powerUpType) {
  powerUpActive = true;
  paddleColor = powerUpColors[powerUpType];
  powerUpFunctions[powerUpType]();
}
function deactivatePowerUp() {
  powerUpActive = false;
  paddleColor = "#0095DD";
}

var StarWars = document.getElementById("myAudio");

var bricks = [];
for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
  bricks[r] = [];
  for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
    bricks[r][c] = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      status: 1
    };
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}

// StarWars.play();

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth / 2;
  }
}

function collisionDetection() {
  for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
      var b = bricks[r][c];
      if (b && b.status == 1) {
        if (x > b.x && x < b.x + brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y + brickHeight) {
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;

          if (score == brickRowCount * brickColumnCount) {
            alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATS!");
            document.location.reload();
          } else {
            //level++
            //brickRowCount++;
            //brickColumnCount++;
            activatePowerUp("extra-life");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = paddleColor;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawBricks() {
  for (var r = 0; r < brickRowCount; r++) {
    for (var c = 0; c < brickColumnCount; c++) {
      if (bricks[r][c].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (c * (brickWidth + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (r * (brickHeight + brickPadding)) + brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[r][c].x = brickX;
        bricks[r][c].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawPowerUp() {
  if (powerUpActive) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(powerUpX, powerUpY, powerUpWidth, powerUpHeight);
    ctx.fillstyle = powerUpColors[powerUpType];
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, 8, 20);
}

function drawLives() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Lives: " + lives, canvas.width - 65, 20);
}

function drawLevel() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Level : " + level, canvas.width / 2 - 30, 20)
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBricks();
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawPowerUp();
  drawLevel();
  drawScore();
  drawLives();
  collisionDetection();

  if (x + dx > canvas.width - ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }
  if (y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  } else if (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius) {
    if (x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      dy = -dy;
      if (x < paddleX + paddleWidth / 2 && dx > 0) {
        dx = -dx;
      } else if (x > paddleX + paddleWidth / 2 && dx < 0) {
        dx = -dx;
      }
    } else {
      lives--;
      if (!lives) {
        alert("GAME OVER");
        document.location.reload();
      } else {
        x = canvas.width / 2;
        y = canvas.height - 30;
        dx = 3;
        dy = -3;
        paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
      }
    }
  }

  if (rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  } else if (leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }

  if (powerUpActive) {
    powerUpY += powerUpSpeed;
    if (powerUpY > canvas.height) {
      deactivatePowerUp();
    } else if (powerUpY + powerUpHeight > canvas.height - paddleHeight && powerUpX && powerUpX < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      activatePowerUp(powerUpType);
      deactivatePowerUp(draw);
    }
  }

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```css
#canvas {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/sJTAxQG.jpeg");
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="950" height="500"></canvas>
```